# adding and deleting input fiel dynamically

Tags: javascript

I have a form in which I have add and minus buttons. On click event it should add a new input field and delete the selected input field correspondingly. Add button functions well in my case but deleting selected input field is not working.
I hope I explained my question properly if not let me know.
 Thanks in advance.

```css
.multivaluebox {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 60%;
}

.form-multivaluebox-textbox {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.btncontainer {
  width: 6%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  margin: 0;
}

.subbutton {
  margin-top: 2px;
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 1%;
  background-color: #0098ff;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.addbutton {
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 1%;
  background-color: #0098ff;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="multivaluebox ">
  <input asp-for="@Model" class=" form-multivaluebox-textbox" value="hello" />
</div>
<div class="btncontainer col-sm-1">

  <input type="button" class="addbutton " onclick="addtextbox(); " value="+" />
  <br />
  <input type="button" class=" subbutton" onclick="deletetextbox();" value="-" />
  <script>
    function addtextbox() {

      var newdiv = document.createElement('div');

      $(newdiv).addClass('multivaluebox');
      newdiv.innerHTML = ' <input asp-for="@Model" class=" form-multivaluebox-textbox" value="@(Model?.Count >= 3 ? Model[2] : null)" id="Labels"  />';
      document.getElementById('wrapper').appendChild(newdiv);

       
    }

    function deletetextbox() {
      var inputlist = document.getElementsByClassName('form-multivaluebox-textbox');
      for (i = 0; i < inputlist.length; i++) {
        if (document.getElementsByClassName('form-multivaluebox-textbox').isActive) {
          $(this).remove();

        }
      }

       
    }
```

Comment: first thing i see: you're trying to get your "form-multivaluebox-textbox" byId, but it's acutally a class

Comment: Hi I tried by class and it still doesn't work

Comment: acutally: how do you select the input that you want to delete?

Comment: I first click on textbox and then click on minus button but I guess I am using the wrong attribute "isActive". I want some script that can decide which is the current selected or active textbox so the function can delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've put this together but it's not perfect.

It will allow you to add items to the wrapper and remove a selected item. However I'd suggest having a remove button at the end of each textbox to be more precise and user friendly.

```js
var currentSelection;
  
  function makeCurrentSelection(element){
    currentSelection = element;
  }
 
    function addtextbox() {

      var newdiv = document.createElement('div');

      $(newdiv).addClass('multivaluebox');
      newdiv.innerHTML = ' <input asp-for="@Model" class=" form-multivaluebox-textbox" value="@(Model?.Count >= 3 ? Model[2] : null)" id="Labels" onfocus="makeCurrentSelection(this)"/>';
      document.getElementById('wrapper').appendChild(newdiv);

       
    }

    
    function deletetextbox() {
      currentSelection.remove(); 
    }
```

```css
.multivaluebox {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 60%;
}

.form-multivaluebox-textbox {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.btncontainer {
  width: 6%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  margin: 0;
}

.subbutton {
  margin-top: 2px;
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 1%;
  background-color: #0098ff;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.addbutton {
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 1%;
  background-color: #0098ff;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper" class="multivaluebox ">
  <input asp-for="@Model" class=" form-multivaluebox-textbox" value="hello" onfocus="makeCurrentSelection(this)">
</div>
<div class="btncontainer col-sm-1">

  <input type="button" class="addbutton " onclick="addtextbox(); " value="+">
  <br>
  <input type="button" class=" subbutton" onclick="deletetextbox();" value="-">
  
</div>
```

Comment: where do you use this undoSelection() function?

Comment: Oops, left that in by accident. Edited question

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect but this will give you some idea regarding how to add/delete elements in JavaScript.

1. Add elements in wrapper div
2. Removes element from wrapper div

Please expand the snippet while executing.

Hope this helps !

```js
function addtextbox() {

      var newdiv = document.createElement('div');

      $(newdiv).addClass('multivaluebox');
      newdiv.innerHTML = ' <input asp-for="@Model" class=" form-multivaluebox-textbox" value="@(Model?.Count >= 3 ? Model[2] : null)" id="Labels"  />';
      document.getElementById('wrapper').appendChild(newdiv);

       
    }

    function deletetextbox() {
      var inputlist = document.getElementsByClassName('form-multivaluebox-textbox');// document.getElementsByClassName()
      
      for (i = 0; i < inputlist.length; i++) {

          var elem = inputlist[0];
    return elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
    

        
      }

       
    }
```

```css
.multivaluebox {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 60%;
}

.form-multivaluebox-textbox {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.btncontainer {
  width: 6%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  margin: 0;
}

.subbutton {
  margin-top: 2px;
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 1%;
  background-color: #0098ff;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.addbutton {
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 1%;
  background-color: #0098ff;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper" class="multivaluebox ">
  <input asp-for="@Model" class="form-multivaluebox-textbox" value="hello" />
</div>
<div class="btncontainer col-sm-1">

  <input type="button" class="addbutton " onclick="addtextbox(); " value="+" />
  <br />
  <input type="button" class=" subbutton" onclick="deletetextbox();" value="-" />
  
  <div ></div>
```

Comment: Yes but again the question is how I deleted the selected textbox and not the one with zero index